# Normalising data with only min and max values

Tags: normalization, data-preprocessing

I'm working with salary datasets and wants to normalize the data as much as possible.
I have data in the form of:

years of experience, salary range

0-1, 28-34

2-5, 32-44

...

Each dataset uses different years of experience range.
How would you go about normalizing this data?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with these data? No any other information, apart from displayed two columns?

Comment: (1) Can you explain what you mean by 'normalize' in this context? That word can have at least half a dozen meanings in various frequently encountered applications. (2) What info do you have on years of experience? (3) The range of a sample depends crucially on the size of a sample. Do you have any idea of the sizes of samples on which your ranges are based? Specifically, for normal data: samples of sizes 10, 100, 1000, and 10,000  have on average ranges of about 3, 5, 6.5, 7.7 standard deviations, respectively (by simulation).

Comment: I used 'normalize' specifically because it has multiple meaning :) I'm not sure how I want the final form of this data to look like. 
What I'm sure I want is take all these datasets using different years of experience range and salary range and put them all in the same form so I can compare them somewhat.
And no I don't always know the sample size or when I know it, I have the size for the whole datasets not by line.
This makes this problem and the resulting output not precise at all but I'm trying to find a not-so-bad methodology.

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know "how I want the final form of this data to look like" then we can't say how you can get there.  For most purposes that I can think of off-hand, normalizing these data would make them *less* comparable, not more, but you have to tell us what you want to be able to do.

Comment: > normalizing these data would make them less comparable.   


I'm really not sure how I would compare: 0-1:28-34 & 0-3: 26-42
Thus my question, if you think it's not really possible then ok but I don't know how to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out min-max-normalization, which works like this:

$$ x_\text{normalized} = \frac{x-x_\text{min}}{x_\text{max}-x_\text{min}}$$

This could be used, for example, to normalize each dataset (for individual experience ranges) to find out how a salary observation compares relative to the minimum and maximum salaries out of this range.

Other types of normalization, as well as linear models of salary based on experience, are (as far as i know) hard to create with only the min+max statistics available.

Comment: min-max seems more useful towards comparing a salary to ranges of salary while what I want is more like normalizing different ranges of data (years and salaries). Does this make sense?